# What beautifier library can I use for user content?

Tags: library, javascript, code-beautification

I know a few code beautification tools (Beautifier, Prettier, ...) that format code so that a source file is easier to read for a human being.

What I'm looking for is a JS library that does the same on code written by users, to be displayed on a web page.

I'm looking for something that could be used pretty much like this:

```
const uafl = new UnbelievablyAwesomeFormattingLibrary() // todo: find that tool
const formattedCode = uafl.formatJs($('#code').text())
$('#code').text(formattedCode)
```

What library can (easily) format text written in Javascript by a user on the fly?

Comment: This may belong on another SE site since its asking for a library, but im not sure where else it might fit.

Also, just as a heads up, "code written by users, to be displayed on a web page" sounds an awful lot like it could be a possible vulerability if the input from users is not sanitized to make sure it doesn't contain any code that can be run on the page or on your servers. This is especially true if users can see code posted by other users. i.e. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zv0kZKC6GAM

Comment: OK, I'll transfer the question to another site, but I don't know which as StackOverflow doesn't accept recommandation requests. As for the vulnerability, I never said the code had to be executed, it will be displayed. I want people to be able to upload their code to show the world, like they would do in a forum, but my library would format it before display.

Comment: honestly this site may be best for it, im still not 100% sure where the line is. 

funnily enough, there seems to be an SO post about this (even though the comments suggest its off topic): https://stackoverflow.com/a/30280786, hope that helps answer your question!